# 0.5×2=1 but 0.5+0.5=1.0. Explain?

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

So when we multiply $0.5$ (approximate number) by $2$ (exact number), we get $1$, since our product must contain as many significant figures as $0.5$.

When we add $0.5$ to $0.5$ (both approximate), we get $1.0$, since our sum must be as precise as the least precise of the above two numbers.

But aren't $0.5+0.5$ and $0.5×2$ the same thing?

(I suspect it has something to do with both the $0.5$ being the same quantity. But it's only a hunch.)

Comment: Is there really a difference between 1 and 1.0?

Comment: How to best use approximations is not an exact science. It's more of an approximate one. Thus you cannot expect that different approaches give the exact same result the way you can with exact calculations. They usually give approximately the same result, however, and in my opinion, this is no exception.

Comment: @randall Yes. 1 is correct to the nearest unit. Its actual value may be 1.3 or 0.7 etc. 1.0 is correct to the nearest tenth. Its actual value may be 1.04 or 0.96 but never 1.3 or 0.7.

Comment: @arthur what if I have to calculate 2×0.5? Usually I would use the rules for multiplication but if think of it like adding two numbers, I get a more precise result. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I guess I'm glad that I don't work in this area, then.  Carry on!

Comment: Haha. Yeah very confusing stuff indeed!

Comment: As I said, how many significant digits you are allowed to carry with you through a calculation _is not an exact science_. It is not a set of strict rules to be adhered to at all times, but rather rules of thumb, allowing you to weigh different concerns and use common sense to finally decide how precice you think your final answer _ought_ to be.

Comment: What would writing 2 like that achieve?

Comment: Product must contain as many significant figures as the least accurate number. When I wrote 2 I assumed it had infinitely many significant figures. 0.5 has 1. So product will always have just 1.

Comment: Note that the leading zero is not a significant digit.

Comment: I never considered it a significant figure.

Comment: In the second case you actually did: in either case, significant digit rules would say that you should only have one significant digit.

Comment: No, I didn't. Rule says that if I have a couple of numbers, that I intend to add, my result must be as _precise_ as the least precise number. NOT accurate. Significant figures won't matter here. The number who's right most digit is the most to the left is the least precise number. Hence my sum will also have its rightmost digit in the exact same place regardless of its magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are "rules of thumb" for numerical calculation, which are only approximately correct.

For $0.5 \times 2$ we have:
$$
\text{if}\quad
\frac{45}{100} < a < \frac{55}{100}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b = 2
\quad\text{then}\quad
\frac{90}{100} < a \times b < \frac{110}{100}
\tag{1}$$
but the conclusion $1.0$ means
$$
\frac{95}{100}< a \times b < \frac{105}{100}
$$
but that conclusion is not (precisely speaking) justified.

For $0.5 + 0.5$ we have
$$
\text{if}\quad
\frac{45}{100} < a < \frac{55}{100}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{45}{100} < b < \frac{55}{100}
\quad\text{then}\quad
\frac{90}{100} < a + b < \frac{110}{100}
\tag{2}$$
but the conclusion $1$ means
$$
\frac{50}{100}< a + b < \frac{150}{100}
$$
so in this case the conclusion is much more than justified.

Note that the conclusions in (1) and (2) are the same, as you asserted.  But the true state of that conclusion is somewhere between $1$ and $1.0$.

Comment: How should I know which rule is more appropriate in a certain situation?

Comment: So the rule for addition isn't always correct but it provides us with a good estimate of the sum; and I'm guessing the rule for multiplication isn't an exact rule as well?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is: in the addition case, you multiply with exactly 2. In the multiplication case, you multiply with approximately 2.

In the addition case, absolute errors add up, which means only the errors in 0.5 add up. You get potentially an error of magnitude $0.05+0.05=0.1$, in which case it makes sense to round to 1.0 (even though the actual result is anywhere between 0.9 and 1.1).

In the multiplication case, relative errors (approximately) add up, so if you have relative errors 10% (from 0.5) and 25% (from 2), your relative error is 35% and the result is (approximately, again) between 0.65 and 1.35, so you know very little about the next digit after 1, that is why it is approximated as just 1. (Try for youself, multiply $0.45 × 1.5$ and $0.55 × 2.5$ and see in which interval the result really fits.)

Comment: But as I said, even if I multiply with exactly 2 the result is the same. 0.5×2=0.5×2.000000000...≈1, since 0.5, our least accurate number, has 1 significant figure.

Comment: One should be careful about the model of error being used. There is the "interval" model that you describe, where you have absolute guarantees on errors. But there is also the "each quantity is normally distributed with a standard deviation much smaller than its mean" model, which has significantly different behavior.

Comment: @Ian I am sure there are refinements for those cases. I tried to give the answer at the level at which I perceive the question was asked.

Comment: @user8734617 Sure, I'm just saying that in any case, even at a rather elementary level, one should make it clear that any model of uncertainty is just a model and is thus only appropriate in certain contexts. In particular, this peculiarity here is essentially a quirk of the "significant figure" model of errors, which is basically an approximation of the "interval" model.

Comment: @Hrit Roy, the rule of thumb that you use for multiplication doesn't take into account whether 2 had one or infinitely many significant digits (as long as it had at least as many than 0.5 had!), thus you cannot expect that it will produce a better estimate of the error than in the case where 2 is also approximate (rather than exact). In the addition case, you actually **use** the fact that 2 is exact so you have a better estimate of the error.